# Arbitrary-length vector of random scalars summing to 1

Tags: matlab

I need to create an Nx1 column vector of random scalars where the sum of all scalars in the vector equal 1. Each scalar in the vector needs to be greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1. The vector can be of variable length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate `N` random values.  Compute their sum.  Divide all values by the sum.

Answer (score 1):

```
function result = randvec(n)
  num = rand(n,1);
  result = num / sum(num);
end
```